# Некорректное отображение символов

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, кодировка

Очередной вопрос на тему кодировки UTF-8 для php и mysql, но просмотренные вопросы не привели к решению.

**Проблема:**

- Если создавать записи в таблице через phpMyAdmin, то все хорошо отображается в phpMyAdmin, а на сайте выглядит так: `????`
- Если создавать записи через php, то на сайте все хорошо: а в phpMyAdmin так: `ÐžÐ»ÐµÐ³`

**Предпринятые меры:**

- в phpMyAdmin у базы/таблицы/строк проставлено сравнение utf8_general_ci:
  [image: utf8_general_ci]
- Проверил установленную в бд кодировку: следуя указанному на данном ресурсе способу https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/convert-mysql-database-utf-8#a-nameprocCurrentCharSetaDetermine-the-current-character-encoding-set:
  [image: character_set_name]
- На страницах сайта в `<head>` прописал:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  ```
- Обращаюсь к mysql из php через `mysqli`. Там проставляю utf8 следующим образом:

  ```
  $conn = new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  $conn->set_charset(UTF8);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Я использовал XAMPP, и нашел решение именно в нем

1. Напротив MySQL нажал на Config
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Далее перешел в редактирование my.ini
3. Домотал до строк `## UTF 8 Settings`
4. Раскомментировал все, что было под этим заголовком, а именно:

   ```
   ## UTF 8 Settings
   init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
   collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
   character_set_server=utf8
   skip-character-set-client-handshake
   character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
   ```
5. Перезагрузил MySQL